# saving c# project as one single text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to save a whole C# solution in one single text file? I vaguely remember a tool (VS add-on?) to do this, but I cannot find it.

**WARNING**: This is highly likely a duplicate, and I would be happy to delete the post if so, but I haven't been able to find the answer in SO.

Comment: Do you have a scenario for this (just trying to satisfy my own personal curiousity)

Comment: I've never heard of one - but... out of curiosity... why?

Comment: @JaredPar - lol; not just me, then ;-p

Comment: For the question, why: Easy source control.  j/k

Comment: How would that make source control any easier? No repo tool worth using would struggle with multiple files in a folder tree...

Comment: maybe he wants to do it for some kind of compression technique for moving the solution around?

Comment: The use case for this (I have it right now) is to be able to paste an entire project as a comment in GitHub on a PR (together with instructions on deserializing it back to a project) where you don't want to create a temporary repo or keep it anywhere other than GitHub, for persistence and posterity purposes (so that the info is forever maintained for the lifetime of the PR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that this would be possible.

A solution consists of a number of completely different file types, each in their own format, with a different purpose:

- **The solution file** is in a legacy (non-XML) text format and informs your IDE (typically Visual Studio) about all the different projects that are part of the solution, as well as pointing it to other files relating to the solution such as test run configuration settings.
- **Project files** these days are XML build files that inform MSBuild what source files are to be built, and how.
- **Source files** contain code of an arbitrary programming language.
- **Other files** a project can also have any other arbitrary text or binary files. (For example, embedded resource images.)

So there we have at least four different file formats: non-XML text, XML, plaintext, and binary.

Perhaps the only way that you could achieve the combination of all these disparate file types into a single file would be to have some mechanism to magically extract all of the separate files out from your single file, present them to the development and build tools as if everything were normal, and then magically re-combine them back into the single file after.

That would be roughly equivalent to taking the entire solution directory and running it through WinZip to produce a single file (a compressed file, to boot!) though perhaps witha more seamless integration via a Visual Studio Add-In.